# Error on download PNG image and assign it to TPNGImage

Tags: windows

I use to download PNG image next code:
If I download image via internetexplorier addresline, I get file same size and context.
(fc result is: FC: no differences encountered)

May be problem in TpngImage.

Please help.

```
..
  ms: TmemoryStream;
  Png: TpngImage;
 ..
    try
      Response.ReadToStream(ms);
      ShowMessage(intToStr(ms.Size));
      ms.Position:= 0;
      ms.SaveToFile('abcxxx.png');
      Try
        Png.LoadFromFile('abcxxx.png');
      Except
      End;
    finally
      Response.Free;
    end;
```

I get error on line png.LoadFromFile('abcxxx.png');
The operation not valid becouse current image contains no valid header.

Only file explorier shows image OK. PNG validator shows that image is valid.

Comment: You forgot to tell us which programming language you use. It looks like Pascal/Delphi.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I use Delphi.
Only problem is resolved. I changes TImage with TcxImage (DevExpress). And all is more simple.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).